# python telegram bot sender filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-3.8, python-telegram-bot

i want to create a handler that trigers when a concret user (@exampleuser) post a message that contains a word in a wordlist.

This is what i have done:
`dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex(re.compile(r'*example word from the wordlist*', re.IGNORECASE)) and Filters.sender_chat(390077500)) , wordBan)`

but it doesnt work but if i only use: `dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.sender_chat(*example user id*)) , wordBan)` it works but instead of triggering when a concret user send the message it triggers when any user does.

How can i add a concret user filter

Answer (score 1):

use

```py
dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex(re.compile(r'*example word from the wordlist*', re.IGNORECASE)) & Filters.sender_chat(390077500)) , wordBan)
```

you want to use `&` and `|` to compose PTB filters.